# localStorage on IE8 / IE9 with localhost or LAN server name doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm using https://github.com/jarednova/jquery-total-storage to access localStorage.  In IE8 and IE9, I'm having a weird issue and it seems to occur even if I just use plain old javascript.

If I go to `http://foo` and use $.totalStorage, it persists through that session but is gone when I close and open IE.

If I go to `http://foo.mydomain.com` and use $.totalStorage, it persists when I close and open IE.

It even occurs when I launch (localhost) debugging from Visual Studio!

In Firefox / Chrome, it persists between sessions regardless of if I got go foo or foo.mydomain.com

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround?

**UPDATE:** To reproduce this, just add this script block to your page, then serve it from `http://localhost` or `http://yourpcname`:

```
<script>
    var storage = window.localStorage;
    alert (storage.foo);
    storage.foo = 'bar!';
</script>
```

The first time you run it on localhost you'll get "undefined".  Then if you refresh you'll get "bar!".  Then if you close out of IE and go back in again, you'll get "undefined" instead of "bar!".

Comment: I ran your test code just fine by the way. It's something specific to your setup.

Comment: I've had 3 friends online able to reproduce it in their setups, one of which is using Linux/nginx as the server.

Answer (score 0):

Sound's like your creating a express IIS or "visual studio development server" every time you launch the debugger.

If you host your web application without creating a express instance every debug, and setting up a permanent application though IIS, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's occurring even if I host it on regular full-blown server 2008 R2 IIS, but access it via the short `http://foo` name rather than the fully qualified `http://foo.mydomain.com` name.

Comment: in which case, I retract this answer, sorry. Could it possible be a security setting on IE? Just an idea... I'm sure you've already checked that... but either way, worth mentioning.

Comment: I thought maybe it was a security setting too, but local storage is enabled in IE and works fine on fully qualified domain names.

Comment: When you run IE8 using an intranet address, IE8 will default to IE7 quirks mode. (Yeah, thanks Microsoft). Could that be relevant? You can force it to IE8 mode using the x-ua-compatible header.

Comment: Worth a whirl, but `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge"/>` didn't change it.  I still get "undefined" on first load with my test case in the OP.